# Trying to override text input height

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I have set the styling for my text inputs as follows:

```
/** INPUTS **/

input{
background:#FFFFFF url(../images/input_bg.png) repeat-x;
border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
margin-bottom:20px;
padding:7px;
-webkit-border-radius:2px;
-moz-border-radius:2px;
}

/** Text Inputs **/

input[type=text].small{
    width:33%;
}

input[type=text].medium{
    width:66%;
}

input[type=text].large{
    width:98%;
}
```

Then I am using a JQuery plug-in that has text inputs and they are being styled the same, the class in question is below:

```
.dataTables_filter {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;   
}
```

So I created a new CSS rule:

```
input.dataTables_filter {
    height: 20px !important;
    background: none !important;
}
```

But I can't seem to make the text input any smaller.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: do you mean the actual text within the input? Try line-height or fontSize

Comment: not the text, the actual height of the text input box. example page is hard to link to as you need to login to see it :/

Comment: How about changing input.dataTables_filter to input[type=text].dataTables_filter ?

Comment: @kei - still the same :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `padding:7px;` on all `input`s.  Combined with the `font-size`, this could be keeping the `height` from shrinking.  Try resetting the `padding`?

Comment: it's a good shout, I'm sure I tried it before-hand, setting the margin and padding to 0 just in case. Tried it again with `padding: 0px !important;` but nothing changed :(

Comment: Also try to adjust the `font-size` for your `input`.

Comment: here is what I have at the moment: `input.dataTables_filter {
     height: 20px !important;
     background: none !important;
     padding: 0px !important;
     font-size: 10px !important; 
}` 

Don't know what's causing it! If I take out the original input rules then it looks fine so don't have a clue why I can't override it.

Comment: Is `input.dataTables_filter` below `input` in order in the stylesheet? If the `input` comes second, it may override the specific styles.

Comment: how about...take the `padding:7px;` out of the `input` rule and - if it works after that... only apply it back to those specific rules that need padding.